# HIVE and myBatis issue with Date/Timestamp fields

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, mybatis

I've code a simple hadoop/hive table defined as

```
CREATE TABLE mike
timeOne TIMESTAMP,
timeTwo TIMESTAMP,
name    STRING
```

And then a myBatis mapper file to insert a record here that looks like this

```
<insert id="insertMikeFormDataForHadoop" parameterType="hashmap">
    INSERT INTO ${tableName} (timeOne, timeTwo, name)
    VALUES (#{timeOne, jdbcType=DATE}, #{timeTwo, jdbcType=DATE}, #{name})
  </insert>
```

When I run a test to insert data via this SQL I get error like this.

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:16 mismatched input '-' expecting ) near '2017' in value row constructor
### The error may involve com.vertexinc.ve.returns.mapper.FormMapper.insertMikeFormDataForHadoop-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: INSERT INTO mike (timeOne, timeTwo, name)     VALUES (?, ?, ?)
### Cause: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:16 mismatched input '-' expecting ) near '2017' in value row constructor
```

I've also tried this with jdbcType=TIMESTAMP instead of date with the same error.

I've wondering if I'm doing something wrong or assuming something about hive/hadoop and mybatis that I shouldn't.

(This is a super simple example I've used to illustrate this point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with the hive jdbc driver version 1.2.1.
The setTimestamp in the HivePreparedStatement had a small defect.  Upgrading driver fixed the issue..

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11748

Comment: can you share some example of how to use mybatis with hive .I couldnot find any